# Revolution Post Based Slider - Only show posts if Categories is "AND"

Tags: wordpress, plugins, revolution-slider

I have a Revolution Slider, set to display as a Post based Slider.

However, I want to set a relation for the Categories to AND, instead of OR.  So the posts will be added to the slider if BOTH Category A and Category B are assigned to the post.

Currently, if I select 2 categories in the Slider settings, it displays posts in Category A OR Category B.  I need it to only show if the post is in BOTH categories - is this possible?

Comment: Please add screenshots, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Screenshots of what?

Comment: Of your slider settings

Comment: Btw: as this is a premium plugin, you should have access to support - did you try that already? Otherwise create a ticket here: https://revolution.themepunch.com/direct-customer-benefits/#ticketsupport

Answer (score 0):

It seems revolution slider does NOT provide [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) operation, just OR.

As a workaround, you could create another category to which you assign only those posts of cat A and B that you want to be displayed by the slider.

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping to avoid that workaround because we have a lot of categories already.

Comment: On the other hand, it is semantically correct to have kind of a main category for posts that have something big enough in common, to show them in the slider. This main can then have sub categories to divide those posts (in my opinion). The amount should not matter, if is is semantically CORRECT, because, whenever you have something which is too big, you create subs - sub directories, sub categories, and so on.

Comment: Sure. Not looking for semantically correct solutions though, as in my case, the current setup doesn't work.  Never mind.